# Chayav Inish - Source of Tune?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, song-poetry, music

What is the origin of [this classic melody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIgt1v6wYNQ) for the popular Purim song "Chayav Inish Lebasumei"?

Comment: In honor of Rosh Chodesh Adar.

Comment: An early *mishloach manot*: [1](http://onthisandonthat.blogspot.com/2012/02/evolution-of-tune.html?m=1), [2](http://onthisandonthat.blogspot.com/2012/03/and-here-i-thought-origins-of-popular.html?m=1) & [3](http://2nd-son.blogspot.com/2010/07/jewish-music.html?m=1).

Comment: @Oliver That got most of the classics.  For some more recent ones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9mxV2KXclE is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alUhI7WUnh4, and shockingly, much of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ajGrQbpf8A is from https://youtu.be/HAazUvOwM9o?t=30 (all links are kol isha free)

Comment: If we talk recent/new songs - loads upon loads are taken from secular songs

Comment: @Oliver true. But Vehi She'amda seems to surprise people, for some reason.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-NYEcaZDAc is based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YccZk1Ao2IY

Comment: @Alex Unlike many others that one was widely reported on ([here](https://www.haaretz.com/1.4677306)), and yet..... see [this](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/.premium-original-jerusalem-of-gold-lyrics-sold-in-special-public-auction-1.6656491) auction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Jewish Music Toronto's video ([here](https://youtu.be/hfElt0_O9_M?t=69)), it comes from the Hungarian Folk song [Szép Asszonynak Kurizálok](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzX5Wz8DJVo).  As an aside, it is also the source of a popular Romanian song ([youtube search link](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=da-ma%20mama%20dupa%20gyuri%20-%20gangnam%20style), but many of the results may include Kol Isha).

H/t to [@EliGreen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9071/eli-green).

---

Edit: Thanks to Oliver for [this link](http://onthisandonthat.blogspot.com/2012/03/and-here-i-thought-origins-of-popular.html?m=1), as at it, a commenter notes:

> My neighbor, R' Yaakov Koppel Reinitz, takes credit for adapting the tune of "Dama Mama Dupa Ghirui" (a gypsy song that he knew from his youth in Hungary) to the words "חייב איניש לבסומי..." He says that he taught it to his talmidim in Yeshivat Kefar haRoeh (in the 1950s or 1960s), and it took off from there.

If this is the case, it seems that the popular Romanian song (Dama Mama Dupa Ghirui) is actually the source, not Szép Asszonynak Kurizálok.  Who knew?

Comment: The lyrics actually mention a gypsy violinist, so it is totally possible that a gypsy song was recycled.